# Bash ignores zip -x arguments

Tags: linux, bash, zip

The script below ignores all the -x exclude arguments when run from bash, but it works fine from command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%u)
ulimit -s 65536

WEEK=`date +"%V"`
if [ $(($WEEK%2)) -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "even";
    BACKUP_DIR="/mnt/backup/2_$TIMESTAMP"
    mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/www"
else
    echo "odd";
    BACKUP_DIR="/mnt/backup/1_$TIMESTAMP"
    mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/www"  
fi

if [ $(date +%u) -gt 6 ];
then
    /usr/bin/zip -r -y $BACKUP_DIR/www/web.zip /var/www/ -x '*/.opcache/*' -x '*/phpThumb/cache/*'
else
    /usr/bin/zip -r -y $BACKUP_DIR/www/web.zip /var/www/ -x '*/mycompany/files/*' -x '*/.opcache/*' -x '*/xml_extras/*' -x '*/files_admin/extras/*' -x '*/chatFiles/*' -x '*/phpThumb/cache/*' -x '*/backup-guard/*' -x '*/mailer/*' -x '*/mycompany/attachments/*'
fi

exit 0
```

Its a 14 day backup solution and I want the weekdays to ignore the bigger folders like images. Any reason the -x arguments gets ignored?

Comment: Note: you tag [tag:bash] but the shebang points to `sh`. You may run the script from Bash but *if* any shell is relevant to the issue then it's `sh` rather than `bash` (unless you *source* from Bash).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks!! I solved it with your comment, after googling the issue with shell, i noticed I need to escape * to \\*

Comment: Frankly I don't really get it yet. Nothing to worry about though. I think if you [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and explain, then your solution and the reason why the original script didn't work will become clear.

Comment: Nevermind its still not working properly (except in command line, thats perfect).

Comment: I formally marked this question as a duplicate. I were you, I would just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the front '*/' and using absolute paths. I still don't know why those worked in terminal and why not in a script with proper parenthesis and escapes.